# Add migrated questions to the 10k tools

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, 10k-tools

Questions that are migrated from other SE sites need special care, especially regarding tagging and rescoping. I suggest an ad-hoc page is added to the 10k mod tools, listing all such questions.

---

Consider for example this question Gaming inherited from Gadgets – or at least, that's what I think happened:

> ### What gadget do you recommend for capturing (high definition) audio and video from my TV/Xbox 360?
>
> I'd like to find a gadget to hook up to my Xbox 360/PS3/TV so that I can record high definition videos of gameplay. What should I get?
>
> `[video] ×4 [video-capture] ×1 [console] ×1`

The question doesn't really fit in Gaming. We'd rather avoid recommendation questions; TV is kind of off-topic; more importantly, we have more specific tags.

Since I happened to stumble on the question, I could fix it:

> ### [How can I capture (high definition) audio and video from my XBox 360?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7551/23)
>
> I'd like to find a gadget to hook up to my Xbox 360/PS3/TV so that I can record high definition videos of gameplay. What should I get?
>
> `[xbox-360] ×147 [ps3] ×75 [recording] ×5`

I'm however worried that more could have fallen through the cracks.

Comment: For now I think the [newly created tags page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tools/new-tags) is the next closest thing currently available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Details of recently imported questions is (at the next build) included in both the 10k tools ("stats" tab, and a fuller-fat version via the "link" tab) and the in-progress [moderator dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72202/moderator-dashboard-help-us-help-you-help-us-all).